# Object of one class not recognised while compiling in another

Tags: java, object, cannot-find-symbol

Let's say in a package using **Java** we are using 2 files.
First one say *StudentModel.java* and second one say *StudentView.java*.

Basic Structure of ***studentModel.java*** is:

```
package student;

public class StudentModel{
    private String name;// name of student
    private int roll;   // roll of student
    private String date;        
    private int marks[]=new int [6];
    private String sub[]=new String[6];
    private int total;

    /*to get the details of a student*/
    public int getRoll();
    public String getDate();

    public String getName();
    public void setDate(String dat);
    public void setName(String nam);
    public void setRoll(int roll);

    public void setSubjectAndMarks(int [] mar,String [] subject){
        for(int i =0;i<6;i++) {
            marks[i]=mar[i];            
            sub[i]=subject[i];
        }
    }

    public void displaySubjectAndMarks(){
        for(int y=0;y<5;y++) {
            System.out.println(sub[y]+"\t \t\t "+marks[y]);
        }
    }

    public int getTotal();  
}
```

and the Basic structure of **StudentView.java** is:

```
package student;

import java.util.*;

public class StudentView {
    /*displaying the marksheet of a particular student*/    
    public void display(StudentModel Obj) { 
        System.out.println("-------------------MARKSHEET---------------");
        System.out.println("\nName:"+Obj.getName()+"\tDate : "+Obj.getDate());
        System.out.println("------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("ROLL NO :\t\t" +Obj.getRoll());
        System.out.println("-------------------------------");
        System.out.println("SUBJECT \t\t MARKS");
        Obj.displaySubjectAndMarks();
        System.out.println("TOTAL"+Obj.getTotal());
    }
}
```

Then first I compiled **StudentModel.java** which gave no errors. Then I compiled **StudentView.java** which raise this error:

```
StudentView.java:18: error: cannot find symbol
public void display(StudentModel Obj) {
symbol:   class StudentModel
location: class StudentView
1 error
```

I am compiling from terminal and, even after adding the class path, I got this error:

[Compilation Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OWpit.png)

Comment: How are you compiling (command line, from within an IDE; If you are not using an IDE, you are making life more difficult for yourself). If compiling from the command line, you must add a "-classpath" to the javac, where the "-classpath" contains the directory where the `studentModel` class resides. BTW, please learn about Java conventions for classnames (start with a Capital), methods (camelCase), etc. It will make it easier for other Java people to read your code.

Comment: What you have sounds like a syntax error. Please provide the actual code, on which the error is given. ```public void display(studentModel Obj);``` is not valid java.

Comment: I am compiling from command line in Ubuntu 14.04 and as you suggested @KevinO i added -classpath to javac and inspite of that I am receiving the same error.You can verify with the picture I have included.

Comment: I have included the details for implementation for *display()* function of *StudentView* class @Jorn

Answer (score 1):

I don't often use the command line for java myself but I was able the reproduce the problem.

What fixed it for me was passing all the source files at once like:

```
javac StudentModel.java StudentView.java
```

There is probably a better solution out there, but I hope this helps in the mean time.

Tip: If you have `make` you can use that to compile, so you don't have to type out everything all the time.

A simpler solution would be to just use an IDE tbh.

**EDIT:**

I got curious and looked into the documentation ([link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html)) Which notes that: *"For .class files in a named package, the class path ends with the directory that contains the "root" package (the first package in the full package name)."*

You're classes are in a package called `student`, so from the class path root, the compiler will look for a folder called 'student' in which to find .class files in the `student` package.

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping me out @Jorn and as for the _package_ _name_ and _folder_ _name_ both are named **student** hence I don't think there is any problem due typo in naming the _folder_ or _package_.
Again thank you

Comment: @AneekRoy Ah, about the latter. I actually meant that the class path should be set to ```/home/some/path/to/sources``` and the .class files should be in ```/home/some/path/to/sources/student``` for classes in the 'student' package.

Comment: Yeah that worked too. I also read the documentation about class path and was confused.Thanks for clarifying @Jorn